# Android 12 | Custom Menu item is not displayed on webview selection highlight

Tags: android, android-studio

```
  @Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {


    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
    if (AppUtil.isChromebookEnvironment() || bookInfoData.getContentImageType().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("ImageBased")) {
        mode.finish();
    }
    TenantReaderManager multiTenancyReaderManager = TenantReaderManager.getInstance();

    selectionModeBar = mode;

    if (pager.isPagingEnabled() == false) {
        return;
    }

    


    // Customize the actionbar
    Menu menu = selectionModeBar.getMenu();
    menu.clear();


    Resources res = getResources();

    try {
        Log.e("name", String.valueOf(menu.getItem(0).getTitle()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    menu.add(0, ReaderConstants.KEY_HIGHLIGHT, 0, " " + res.getString(R.string.native_reader_activity_popup_highlight)).setOnMenuItemClickListener(onMenuItemclick)
            .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    menu.add(0, ReaderConstants.KEY_NOTES, 0, " " + res.getString(R.string.native_reader_activity_popup_note)).setOnMenuItemClickListener(onMenuItemclick)
            .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    try {
        Log.e("name", String.valueOf(menu.getItem(0).getTitle()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

1. Default Menu is displayed, custom items(i.e copy, share, select all) are not getting reflecting.
   But the title is getting printed after adding it to the menu, provided that menu.clear() is working fine as I have log statement after menu.clear()

This code is working in Android 11 and below.

[image]

Comment: After 2 days of research and development, I got the solution, We need to invalidate the Action mode item after adding a custom item inside it.

Invalidate the content rect associated to this ActionMode. This only makes sense for
action modes that support dynamic positioning on the screen, and provides a more efficient way to reposition it without invalidating the whole action mode.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I was in the same boat. 2 days of nothing until I see your comment. Exactly what was needed!

Comment: @Akshatsharma would you kindly put it as an answer with some code along. It will be very helpful.

Comment: mode.invalidate() is adding back the default items as select all and copy. Any idea how to make sure they are not added back?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code for your solution? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mode.invalidateContentRect();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for this!!! my problem was that on some devices (like OnePlus) the app did not show my custom webview text selection menu on selecting the text. Instead it showed default menu. I thought it was problem with webview implementation on this device, but this was kind of refresh problem.